# Override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation defined in Category

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I have the following category defined to allow orientation in a `TabBarController`

```
@implementation UITabBarController (MyApp) 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

@end
```

Now there are a couple of `viewcontroller`s where I don't want to allow landscape-mode. Because I used categories the methods in the `viewcontroller`s are ignored. Is there a way to solve this?

(I know you can subclass `UITabBarController` but this is discouraged by Apple themself).

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the current view controller in your category like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [[self selectedViewController] shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```

You might want to implement some more logic, depending on your needs. Also, subclassing is better in your case than a custom category, overwriting things globally might break at some point in the future.

Comment: Doesn't seem te work. Is it because there are NavigationControllers inside the TabBarController in my example? So there is a second category on UINavigationController defined, but with the same code.

Comment: Is it possible to give some more information about subclassing. What is the most clean en future-proof way when using NavigationControllers inside TabBarControllers. The only thing I want to add, is that I can set a different Orientation for each child view controller.